# Error in split.default(x1, as.vector(gl(length(x1), 2, length(x1)))) : first argument must be a vector

Tags: r

i'm using a code to delete duplicate in list of pairs the code is 
`v<-lapply(v,function(y){x1 <- unlist(y)
l1 <-unique(lapply(split(x1,as.vector(gl(length(x1), 2,length(x1)))), sort))
do.call(set,lapply(l1, function(y) pair(y[1], y[2])))`
where v is the list of pairs , sometimes the code working in proper way but somtimes it give me this error "Error in split.default(as.vector(x1), as.vector(gl(length(x1), 2, length(x1)))) : 
  first argument must be a vector"
in this case the list of pairs appears like this {(1,2),(4,6),(2,1),(6,4)} while if it's working in a correct way the list would be {(1,2),(4,6)}

Comment: @akrun hello my friend ,it doesn't matter it can be any list of integer pairs

Comment: x<-vector(mode = "list",length = 2)
x[[1]]<-set(pair(1,2))
x[[1]]<-append(x[[1]],set(pair(2,1)))
x[[2]]<-set(pair(4,5))
x[[2]]<-append(x[[2]],set(pair(5,4)))                                                                        my expected result x[1] to be {(1,2)} ,x[2] to be {(4,5)}

Comment: i'm using sets package,igraph package